# Removing dynamically added row from table having struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

i am quite new at this and i what to know  how can i get a index row from a dynamical table created with struts2. Here is what i have tried so far:

**test file**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover"
        id="exp">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center"></th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>           
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <s:if test="listanume.size>0">
            <s:iterator value="listanume" status="statusVar">
                <tr>
                    <td class="center">
                            <button class="btn" onclick="javascript:setval(0)">
                                delete
                            </button>
                    </td>
                    <td><s:property value="nume"/></td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:if>
    </tbody>
</table>
<h4>Numarul randului este: <s:property value="mysample"/> </h4>

    <script>
        var mysample= '';
        function= setval(varval){
            mysample=varval;
            alert(mysample);
        }
    </script>
```

**pop java**

```
public class Pop {
private int nrrow;
 private List<UserModel> listanume = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

 UserModel user = new UserModel(),
        user1 = new UserModel(),
        user2 = new UserModel();

 private String[] sample;

 {
     sample = new String[]{"list1", "list2", "list3"};
 }


 public String execute() {

    user.setEmail("eret@esre");
    user.setPass1("1234");
    user.setNume("gigel");

    user1.setEmail("yuii@ihj");
    user1.setPass1("6789");
    user1.setNume("marius");

    user2.setEmail("nmnn@cvx");
    user2.setPass1("7676");
    user2.setNume("sorin");

    sample1.add(user);
    sample1.add(user1);
    sample1.add(user2);

    return "succes";
 }

 public String afisnrow(){

    execute();
    listanume=sample1;

    return "succes";
 }

 public String[] getSample() {
    return sample;
 }

 public void setSample(String[] sample) {
    this.sample = sample;
 }

 public List<UserModel> getSample1() {
    return sample1;
 }

 public void setSample1(List<UserModel> sample1) {
    this.sample1 = sample1;
 }

 public void setNrrow(int nrrow){
    this.nrrow=nrrow;
 }

 public int getNrrow(){
    return nrrow;
 }

 public List<UserModel> getListanume(){
    return listanume;
 }

 public void setListanume(List<UserModel> listanume){
    this.listanume=listanume;
 }
}
```

every row has a button on it and when i  click that button i need to get the row index, i kind of stuck and run out of ideas, any suggestions?

Comment: are you creating dynamic table using jquery?

Comment: now i am using struts2 for creating the table , as you see i am using <S:iterator>

Comment: You are calling `setval` function with 0 passed in every row. What you have tried to put there?

Comment: I just wanted to select the first row from the table

Comment: So with what exactly you are having problems? And what have you tried?

Comment: i can't get the java file to return the argument i've sent, (in my case 0). And the main idea that on each row is a button and when i click that buton i want to get and disply the row index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace 
        `onclick="javascript:setval(0)"`

with

`onclick="javascript:setval(<s:property value="#statusVar.index" />)"`

more info on the struts2 iterator tag [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/iterator.html).

Comment: this is right but, i won't use it since it isn't waht i need, insted this answer gave me an ideea how to rezolve this problem.

Comment: great. Please share what you have done instead as a comment so that other people benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution i have found is this:

**test file**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover"
    id="exp">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center"></th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>           
</thead>

<tbody>
    <s:if test="listanume.size>0">
        <s:iterator value="listanume" status="statusVar">
            <tr>
                <td class="center">
                        <button class="btn" id="<s:property value='indexrow'/>">
                            delete
                        </button>
                </td>
                <td><s:property value="nume"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:if>
</tbody>
</table>

<i><p id="test"> No button pressed.</p></i>

<script>
$("button").click(function(e){
    var idClicked = e.target.id;
$("#test").html(idClicked);
});
</script>
```

**pop java**

```
public class Pop {
private int indexrow;
private List<UserModel> listanume = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

 UserModel user = new UserModel(),
          user1 = new UserModel(),
          user2 = new UserModel();

 public String execute() {

    user.setEmail("eret@esre");
    user.setPass1("1234");
    user.setNume("gigel");

user1.setEmail("yuii@ihj");
user1.setPass1("6789");
user1.setNume("marius");

user2.setEmail("nmnn@cvx");
user2.setPass1("7676");
user2.setNume("sorin");

listanume.add(user);
listanume.add(user1);
listanume.add(user2);

return "succes";
 }

 public String afisnrow(){

   execute();
   for (UserModel userModel : listanume) {
        UserModel userModel1=new UserModel();
        indexrow++;

        userModel1.setNume(userModel.getNume());
        userModel1.setIndexrow(indexrow);

        listanume.add(userModel1);

    }
   return "succes";
 }

   public List<UserModel> getListanume(){
     return listanume;
  }

   public void setListanume(List<UserModel> listanume){
     this.listanume=listanume;
  }
 }
```